# Installing jenkins service from web start causes java.lang.error

Tags: windows, jenkins, java-web-start, slave

I can launch a jenkins slave on a windows 7 machine using Java Web Start.  It works fine, but when I select to install it as a service I get this error:

[image: jenkins error]

It looks like there is a problem on the low level unpacking of data structures, but I have no idea what the root cause is.  Both master and slave machines are windows 7.1. and the jenkins version is 1.588 (latest available).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been filed as [Jenkins JIRA Ticket 25492](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25492).  Please see if that instance is the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks, that looks the same - I will try to downgrade my version of jenkins

Comment: There is another bug report for this - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25358 it seems to be fixed in the latest release